# If an orthogonal matrix has all its eigenvalues equal to $-1$, what can we say about this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Geometrically, what properties would this matrix have?

Comment: It will be minus the identity matrix.

Comment: By the spectral theorem on orthogonal matrices, it represents the opposite of the identity transformation. In paticular, such a matrix must be $-I$ ($I$ is the identity matrix).

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the matrix. Then $\det A = \prod \lambda_i = (-1)^n \in \{ -1, 1 \}$, where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues and $n$ is the dimension.

This means for even dimensions it is a rotation and for odd dimension the product of $n$ reflections.